# Responsive fixed nav menu error on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar fixed in bootstrap. All menus should be center and the logo should respond according to the device e.i, mobile, ipad, netbook, desktop, etc. Also, I want the logo be appeared on mobile while button toggle is displayed.

Unfortunately, the menus goes down when viewed on smaller devices like netbook. Also, I am having problem with the mobile version.

Here is the jsfiddle : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wa74tfsh/1/)

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
    background: #000;
    height: 120px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .container{
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hi is this what you want to create  https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/LLVreo?editors=1100

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, The logo should be at the CENTER of the menus. Also, the navbar texts should at the center as seen on the image.